# Terraform Azure : using resource name automatically on the display name groupe creation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

how can i use the name of ressource  as display_name without repeate action for each ressource, in the bellow my exemple, i want use the same template i change juste the resource "azuread_group" "name" :

```
resource "azuread_group" "dataops" {
  display_name     = "azad-rbac-grp-dataops"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.azad.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}
resource "azuread_group" "finops" {
  display_name     = "azad-rbac-grp-finops"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.azad.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}
resource "azuread_group" "archi" {
  display_name     = "azad-rbac-grp-archi"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.azad.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}
resource "azuread_group" "secops" {
  display_name     = "azad-rbac-grp-secops"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.azad.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}
```

thanks

Comment: Please check the answer and the suggestions to see if it helpful to you. Then you can sign it as a correct one to benefit others.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. Instead you should use a `map` or a `list`  with `count` or `for_each`. For example:

```
variable "name" {
  default = ["dataops","finops","archi","secops"]
}
```

then you use `for_each`:

```
resource "azuread_group" "rg" {

  for_each         = toset(var.name)

  display_name     = "azad-rbac-grp-${each.key}"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.azad.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}
```

Once this is done you can refer to individual `rg` as:

```
azuread_group.rg["dataops"].display_name
azuread_group.rg["finops"].display_name
# and so on
```